# deploying segnet-predict on jetson nano using matlab .:fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

Tags: matlab, cmake, nvidia-jetson-nano

i am working on jetson nano and trying to implement the example of segnet_predict deploy to jetson nao from the matlab.but when i run the command
codegen('-config ', cfg, 'segnet_predict', '-args', {img},'-report');
i get this error:

```
STDERR: /home/remoteBuildDir/MATLAB_ws/R2021b/C/Users/DELL/Documents/MATLAB/segnet_deploy/main.cu:10:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

STDOUT: make: Entering directory '/home/remoteBuildDir/MATLAB_ws/R2021b/C/Users/DELL/Documents/MATLAB/segnet_deploy/codegen/exe/segnet_predict'

------------------------------------------------------------------------
??? Build error: C++ compiler produced errors. See the Build Log for further details.
```

can you please help me resolving this error

i tried to change the path by locating the opencv path but could not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is with the OpenCV library, which the code is trying to include but is unable to find. Check if the OpenCV library is installed on your Jetson Nano:

Run the command

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

in the terminal. If the output is a version number, OpenCV is installed.
If OpenCV is not installed, install it using the command

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

Ensure that the path to the OpenCV header files is included in the compiler search path:

Locate the path to the OpenCV header files (opencv2/opencv.hpp) on your system.
In your MATLAB code, add the path to the OpenCV header files to the compiler search path using the "-I" option in the "codegen" function. For example:
codegen('-config ', cfg, 'segnet_predict', '-args', {img},'-report', '-I /path/to/opencv/headers');

Make sure that the OpenCV libraries are in the library search path:

Locate the path to the OpenCV libraries on your system.
In your MATLAB code, add the path to the OpenCV libraries to the library search path using the "-L" option in the "codegen" function. For example:
codegen('-config ', cfg, 'segnet_predict', '-args', {img},'-report', '-L /path/to/opencv/libraries');